# How do you represent a vector that points to an arbitrary point on a sphere of radius R?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

Is it just

$$v = R \hat{r} + \theta\hat{\theta} + \psi \hat{\psi}$$

That doesn't seem right as the unit is not correct.

Comment: Just $R\hat{r}$. Think again what $\hat{r}$ is.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about that too, but I got confuse on how do you differentiate between a vector that is $-\hat{z}$ and a vector that is $+\hat{z}$ that is on the sphere